# Why does moderncv requires the usage of so many packages?

Tags: packages, moderncv

I'm trying to build my resume using `moderncv`, and I haven't even compiled a working pdf (I just have what's below) because it keeps asking me to install so many packages, like `everyshi`, and `pgf`, etc. I don't understand why I need these packages, as the tutorials that I have come across don't even mention these. I can't even download `everyshi` through MikTex, either, so I don't know how to even proceed. Is there a point of even having all of these packages, and is there a way for me to get it all at once?

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\name{}{}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't MikTeX automatically offer which package to install?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot really tell you *why* `moderncv` loads all those packages, other than the fact that it uses the functionality provided there.  Your MWE has the line

```
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
```

This in turn triggers loading of [`moderncvstyleclassic.sty`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~xdanaux/moderncv/trunk/view/head:/moderncvstyleclassic.sty) which has the line

```
\moderncvicons{marvosym}
```

This loads [`moderncviconsmarvosym.sty`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~xdanaux/moderncv/trunk/view/head:/moderncviconsmarvosym.sty) and this file has

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
```

and of course Ti*k*Z loads PGF and the [LaTeX driver of PGF](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/master/tree/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def#l112) loads `everyshi`.

---

If you don't want this to happen you could redefine `\moderncvicons` to do nothing before loading the theme, i.e.

```
\renewcommand\moderncvicons[1]{}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
```

but for this to work you'd have to make sure that you do not use any definitions from [`moderncviconsmarvosym.sty`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~xdanaux/moderncv/trunk/view/head:/moderncviconsmarvosym.sty) anywhere and I don't think that this is guaranteed.

Comment: TBH, I just installed everything that MikTex kept asking me to. Figured there was no point in protesting it.